# Want to move a Particula column data in Tableview Javafx

Tags: javafx

I want to move a particular column from my tableview

In diagram i want to move only F.Name and OM... column data on click of up button and Down Button and IO ID should Should not move ... as depicted in diagram in java fx.

My Code is :

```
int index = otableview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex);

// swap items
otableview.getItems().add(index - 1, otableview.getItems().remove(index));
// select item at new position
otableview.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(index - 1);
```

from this code it move all the column data ,but i want the code to move only F. Name and OM Column data  and IOID column should not move on click of up and down button.

[image]

KIndly tell me a logic to do it

Comment: Obviously you need to modify the data structure the `cellValueFactory`s of those columns take the data from. Post some information the datastructure you're using and about the `cellValueFactory`s please.

Comment: my  data structure used in my code :
---------------------------------------------------
ocolIo_id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<InputMappingFieldModel,Integer>("iomapid"));
ocolFieldName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<InputMappingFieldModel, String>("fieldname"));
ocolFileOutputMappingId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<InputMappingFieldModel, Integer>("immapid"));

Comment: This is useful for everyone who reads the question. Also its hard to read in the comments. Please [edit] the question and add the info there.